# How to create an object of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a collection in mongodb with a value o type array with 12 rows in it. See the screenshot:
[image]

In my code  make an axios request in the componentDidMount and successfully get the respone and values

```
async componentDidMount() {

    const {data: locations} = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/try1');
    this.setState({locations})
    console.log(locations)

    // Use processCsvData helper to convert csv file into kepler.gl structure {fields, rows}
    const data = Processors.processCsvData(nycTrips);
    console.log(data)

    // Create dataset structure
    const dataset = {
      data,
      info: {
        // `info` property are optional, adding an `id` associate with this dataset makes it easier
        // to replace it later
        id: 'my_data'
      }
    };
    // addDataToMap action to inject dataset into kepler.gl instance
    this.props.dispatch(addDataToMap({datasets: dataset}));
}
```

The problem is I am getting the location object like shown in this screenshot:

[image]

but my required output is as shown below:

[image]

I need the required output to pass it to my mapping application so that the map markers can be generated.

Please advise how I can create an object in the required format.

Following is my simple get api:

```
app.get('/try1', (req, res) => {
    try1.find()
    .then(data => res.json(data))
})
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: what does the code of the api endpoint look like? I think you should be transforming the object in the desired format there

Comment: I have updated the code to include the api server code, its just an standard get request.

Comment: do you store the `rows` in the database as a single string with space separated values?

Comment: That is because the first is the one I am trying to create, the second one is by using a csv import in the original exmple: see the line:
const data = Processors.processCsvData(nycTrips);

Comment: No, the values are stored in mongodb collection as an array of objects. object has 4 entries. See the screenshot in the OP

Comment: does the object in mongoldb have any other properties other than `fields` ?

Comment: yes, there is another property called rows. But that is not important for this.

Comment: What I understand from the question and the comments ... the OP has not and will not have a server side process which generates the response data in its expected/needed form. Thus the transformation has to be done by the client. Is this correct? If yes, one needs to know how to split the `row`'s string value into valid row items (what kind of pattern is there / can be utilized)?